# Problema com retorno undefined de função

Tags: javascript, funções, return

Boa noite, fiz o seguinte algoritmo em JavaScript:

```
var res = 1;
console.log(fatorial(3));

function fatorial(n){
    if(n == 1){
        console.log(res);
        return(res);
    }else{
        res *= n;
        fatorial(n - 1);
    }
}
```

No **console.log(res)** o resultado aparece corretamente, enquanto no **console.log(fatorial(3))** aparece a mensagem **undefined**. Alguém poderia me esclarecer a razão disso e como fazer para que em ambos apareça o resultado?

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta retornar o fatorial no seu `else`:

```
else{
    res *= n;
    return fatorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Foi uma coisa que não me atentei, resolveu meu problema.